# Gene APOA2 SNP rs5082 alleles are A or G, but papers describe it with CC and TT?

Tags: genetics

rs5082 is a SNP in the APOA2 gene. It is associated with obesity and heart disease risk.

According to this article the alleles can be A or G
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs5082#frequency_tab

Why does this article only discuss CC or TT?  Where is the A or G?
https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/108/1/188/5036568

Comment: It is probably a matter of strand. Check which DNA strand authors of both papers refer to - forward or reverse.

Answer (score 1):

The rsID letters are assigned based on the **genome** being the default "forward" direction while the researchers on that gene think of the nucleotides of the context of the **transcript**, (or in this case the promotor sequence) which runs backwards.